# Encode mp4 video with just audio

Tags: cordova, ffmpeg, mp4

I am working on a cordova app for iOS and Android and the app works on all devices I've tested except the OnePlus, where the audio does not work but the video does.  I've tried ogg and mp3 but to no avail.  However, mp4 videos play perfectly.

As a hackish solution, I'd like to make all of my audio mp4 video that has no images and just audio.  Is this possible using ffmpeg or another too and will it play in the video tag?  If all else fails I can create a video with a single stock image, but I'm afraid that the result will be larger than what I'm looking for.

Comment: _I'd like to make all of my audio mp4 video that has no images and just audio. Is this possible using ffmpeg or another too and will it play in the video tag?_ Could you please rephrase your question, it's really confusing. You want to create an audio only .mp4 file? What do you mean with  _the video tag_?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an audio only mp4 file if you want. mp4 is a container format and can include one to many different streams of audio, video, subtitle etc.

mp4 audio streams are usually encoded with AAC codec.

Also, audio only mp4 usually use the m4a extension.

In ffmpeg, you could use a command like `ffmpeg -i input.wav -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128k output.m4a` You can find more details about aac encoding [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC)